# 'Dimension too large' when `useasboundingbox` with `fill between`

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween, bounding-box

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
    X   Y       CI95
    1   1.50    0.39
    2   1.05    0.21
    3   0.50    0.14
    4   0.20    0.05
    5   0.35    0.35
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (5.0,5.0);
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot [name path=lower] table [x=X,y expr=\thisrow {Y} - \thisrow {CI95}
]{data.txt};
\addplot [name path=upper] table [x=X, y expr=\thisrow{Y} + \thisrow{CI95}]{data.txt};
\addplot[green!40] fill between[of=lower and upper];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Output is correct:

[image]

But error in logs:

```
! Dimension too large.
\pgfplotspointupperrightcorner ...f@x =-32000.0pt 
                                                  \global \pgf@y =-32000.0pt 
l.25 \end{axis}
               
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

! Dimension too large.
\pgfplotspointupperrightcorner ...f@y =-32000.0pt 
                                                  
l.25 \end{axis}
               
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

Comment: Why you need `bounding box`? If you move it inside of `axis` environment (where image dimension id defined) compilation works, however it not influence on your image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of setting the bounding box at the beginning you can reset it in the end and then set it. This avoids the errors which you mention. In general this is preferable since this allows you to measure things without problems e.g. using a `local bounding box`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{data.txt}
    X   Y       CI95
    1   1.50    0.39
    2   1.05    0.21
    3   0.50    0.14
    4   0.20    0.05
    5   0.35    0.35
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot [name path=lower] table [x=X,y expr=\thisrow {Y} - \thisrow {CI95}
]{data.txt};
\addplot [name path=upper] table [x=X, y expr=\thisrow{Y} + \thisrow{CI95}]{data.txt};
\addplot[green!40] fill between[of=lower and upper];
\end{axis}
\pgfresetboundingbox
\path[use as bounding box] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (5.0,5.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks! :)